# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'

Tags: python, django, web

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

I am using dgango and its my first project and shows error after adding the above line in views.py file:

File "C:\Users\iamab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf_*init*_.py", line 80, in **getattr**
val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'

Comment: Did you put a `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: no, I am just following the tutorial and he didn't added STRIPE_SECRET_KEY in settings.py. (can u quide how to do it)

Comment: also, i would never add a "SECRET KEY" to settings.py - this thing is directly uploaded on github for the public!

please use python-dotenv and get rid of this backdoor

https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have that variable inside `settings.py` (almost anywhere). Like:

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = "asQEfg92mf-Wafoi#k9"
```

But it's much better idea to store in your environment variables, i.e. in System configuration or [in 'env' file](https://alicecampkin.medium.com/how-to-set-up-environment-variables-in-django-f3c4db78c55f).

PS there is safer way to get values from settings. Instead of:

```
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
```

Use:

```
stripe.api_key = getattr(settings, "STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", "")
```

Then there might be warmer warning if there is missing variable, i.e.:

```
if not stripe.api_key:
    print("Hey! 'stripe.api_key is missing!'")
```